# OpenGL in Xamarin

Tags: opengl, xamarin, uwp, win-universal-app

I'm currently developing the cross-platform application for Android, iOS and UWP (Universal Windows Platform). I have found OpenGL examples for iOS and Android, but did not find any of them for UWP. 
So, the question is, How can I use OpenGL in UWP applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL does not run out-of-the-box with the Universal Windows Platform. A solution to this is [ANGLE](https://blog.chromium.org/2010/03/introducing-angle-project.html) that layers WebGL's subset of the OpenGL ES APIs over DirectX API calls.

Useful NuGet packages can be found [here](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/angle) but I don't know how this can be implemented in a Xamarin project, if it can be implemented at all.